# Error in creating firehose cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am creating a "firehose" cloudformation template that will eventually push data to redshift

It looks something like this:

```
{
  "Resources": {
     "Role1" : {},// this role permits access to S3 and Redshift

     "S3Bucket" : {} // configuration for S3 bucket where firehose places data before pushing it to redshift

     "RedshiftCluster": {} // configuration for redshift cluster

     "FirehoseStream": {
        ... some properties here
       "RedshiftDestinationConfiguration" : {
           "ClusterJDBCURL": {
            "Fn::GetAtt": [
              "RedshiftCluster",
              "ClusterJDBCURL"
            ]
         }

        },

     }
  }


}
```

The error I receive is :

```
Template validation error: Template error: resource RedshiftCluster does not support attribute type ClusterJDBCURL in Fn::GetAtt
```

As per the docs the value for ClusterJDBCURL has to be a "String". However, I will not know the value of this string until the redshift cluster is setup.

How then am i suppose to provide this value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AWS::Redshift::Cluster](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-redshift-cluster.html#w2ab2c21c10d872c11) type does not have a ClusterJDBCURL attribute.
We can however construct one using [Fn::Sub](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html).

Based on the [Obtain the JDBC Url](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html#obtain-jdbc-url) documentation, a **JDBC Url** is in the form `jdbc:redshift://<endpoint>:<port>/<database>`.

So, if you replace `<database>` in the following example with the name of your database, you should get what you're looking for.

```
{
  "Resources": {
    "Role1" : {},// this role permits access to S3 and Redshift
    "S3Bucket" : {} // configuration for S3 bucket where firehose places data before pushing it to redshift

    "RedshiftCluster": {} // configuration for redshift cluster

    "FirehoseStream": {
        ... some properties here
      "RedshiftDestinationConfiguration" : {
        "ClusterJDBCURL": {
          "Fn::Sub": "jdbc:redshift://${RedshiftCluster.Endpoint.Address}:${RedshiftCluster.Endpoint.Port}/<database>"
        }
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where did you learn about properties like "RedshiftCluster.Endpoint.Address" . I am scanning through all documentation and cannot find reference to this feature ?

Comment: In the **Fn::GetAtt** section of the [AWS::Redshift::Cluster](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-redshift-cluster.html#w2ab2c21c10d872c11), it has an `Endpoint.Address` and `Endpoint.Port`. sub takes the name of a resource and attributes and allows you to sub with them.

Comment: Updated answer. I think I was using the wrong form of fn::sub. Should be  "Fn::Sub": "jdbc:redshift://${RedshiftCluster.Endpoint.Address}:${RedshiftCluster.Endpoint.Port}/<database>"

Answer (score 0):

Another syntax, useful inside serverless.yml

```
          ClusterJDBCURL:
            Fn::Join:
              - ""
              - - "jdbc:redshift://"
                - Fn::GetAtt: [RedShiftCluster, Endpoint.Address]
                - ":"
                - Fn::GetAtt: [RedShiftCluster, Endpoint.Port]
                - "/<database>"
```